# Magento - removing products from the cart

Tags: php, function, magento, magento-1.9

I need to remove cart products from a certain category (category with id = 13) when the page loads, if there is a product added to the cart from that category. I've been working on this for quite a while and researching it too, but I did not find anything that could help me to do the function to get the result I want. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try some code that you can share here ?

Comment: @MahmoodRehman I would not have, because I have not found anything that could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using magento Observer event i.e **checkout_cart_save_before**. I have achieve this by creating following module that does not allow the user to add product into the cart of specific category.

You need to create a module for this :

1. Create Module registration file under **app/etc/modules/Tanymart_Removecart.xml** with following code :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Tanymart_Removecart>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>community</codePool>
           </Tanymart_Removecart>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```
2. Now under the **community** codepool, create **config.xml** file. File Path is **app/code/community/Tanymart/Removecart/etc/config.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Tanymart_Removecart>
               <version>0.1.0</version>
           </Tanymart_Removecart>
       </modules>
        <global>
           <models>
               <tanyremovecart>
                   <class>Tanymart_Removecart_Model</class>
               </tanyremovecart>
           </models>
         <events>
               <checkout_cart_save_before>
                   <observers>
                       <remove_category_item>
                           <class>Tanymart_Removecart_Model_Observer</class>
                           <method>removeCategoryCart</method>
                       </remove_category_item>
                   </observers>
               </checkout_cart_save_before>
           </events>
        </global>   
        <frontend>
           <routers>
               <tanyremovecart>
                   <use>standard</use>
                   <args>
                       <module>Tanymart_Removecart</module>
                       <frontName>tanyremovecart</frontName>
                   </args>
               </tanyremovecart>
           </routers>
         </frontend>
   </config>
   ```
3. Now create **Observer.php** inside **Model** directory. File Path **app/code/community/Tanymart/Removecart/Model/Observer.php** with following code :

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * @category    Tanymart
    * @package     Tanymart_Removecart
    * @author      Bachcha Singh
    * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2017
    * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
    */
   class Tanymart_Removecart_Model_Observer {
       public function removeCategoryCart($observer){
           $items = $observer->getEvent()->getCart()->getItems();
           $oCheckout = Mage::getSingleton( 'checkout/session' );
           $oQuote    = $oCheckout->getQuote();
           foreach($items as $item) {
                   $_product = $item->getProduct();
                       if(in_array(13, $_product->getCategoryIds())) {
                                $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                                 $oQuote->removeItem($itemId)->save();
                       }
                   }

       }
   }
   ```

Replace **13** above with your specific category.

That's it.
Hope it will help you.